# Как распознать русские буквы

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имеется такой код:

```html
class Router
{
 protected $routes = array();
 protected $params = array();
 
 public function __construct()
 {
  $arr = require 'config/routesConfig.php';
  foreach($arr as $key => $val)
  {
   $this->add($key, $val);
  }
 }
 
 public function add($route, $params)
 {
  $route = preg_replace('/{([a-z]+):([^\}]+)}/', '(?P<\1>\2)', $route);
  $route = '#^'.$route.'$#';
  $this->routes[$route] = $params;
 }

 public function match()
 {
  $url = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
        foreach ($this->routes as $route => $params) 
  {
            if (preg_match($route, $url, $matches))
   {
                foreach ($matches as $key => $match) 
    {
                    if (is_string($key)) 
     {
                        if (is_numeric($match)) 
      {
       $match = (int) $match;
                        }
                        $params[$key] = $match;
                    }
                }
                $this->params = $params;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
 }
 
 public function run()
 {
  if($this->match())
  {
   $path = 'controllers\\'.ucfirst($this->params['controller']).'Controller';
   if(class_exists($path))
   {
    $action = $this->params['action'].'Action';
    if(method_exists($path, $action))
    {
     $controller = new $path($this->params);
     $controller->$action();
    }
    else
    {
     View::errorCode(404);
    }
   }
   else
   {
    View::errorCode(404);
   }
  }
  else
  {
   View::errorCode(404);
  }
 }
}
```

config/routesConfig.php  содержит :

```
return array(
'search/{text:\w+}' => array(
    'controller' => 'main',
    'action' => 'search',
),
);
```

{text:\w+} это именованная подмаска. Она работает только с английскими буквами. Как переделать что бы работала и с русскими? Я так понял, что нужно добавить /u, но у меня не получается

Answer (score 1):

Да, верно, необходимо строку

```
$route = '#^'.$route.'$#';
```

исправить на строку

```
$route = '#^'.$route.'$#u';
```

После этого всё должно заработать ка Вы хотите.

Comment: к сожалению не помогло(

Comment: Поизучал вопрос. Попробуйте в дополнение к изменению выше заменить в config/routesConfig.php "{text:\w+}" на "{text:\pL+}". Судя по отзывам людей, это косяк в какой-то относительно старой версии pcre. В более новых его починили уже.

Comment: не помогает(( А как обновить pcre?

Comment: я использую денвер у него и версия php старая, может его заменить на что нибудь по новее?

Comment: Ну это вам решать :)  Я давно перешёл на виртуальные машины. Связку VirtualBox + Vagrant чуть сложнее в начале настраивать, зато вы получаете полноценный тестовый сервер (или несколько, если надо), который поднимается одной командой. И так же лихо при необходимости может быть перенастроен или "обнулён".

Comment: @helldrg, Денвер в целом давно устарел - настолько, что сейчас его использование вредно. Если на компе мало оперативки для вирт. машины, можно зарегаться на 000webhost (для учебной практики его хватит )

Comment: @yar85 спасибо!

Comment: @Limych проверил на новом сервере, все равно не работает(